# Why does integration only work. The equation of motion v=u+at gives a different answer.

Tags: calculus, integration

If given that a particle starts from rest when time t=0. It ravels with acceleration (24t-16)m/s/s. where t is time measured from the instant when the particle is at rest. find its velocity when t=3.

I know you have to differentiate to get your answer but why does it not work when I use the equations of motion: v=u+at. I get 2 completely different answers please explain. When i integrate i get v=60m/s when I use the formula I get v=168m/s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get the formula $v=u+at$ when $a$ is constant but it is not the case here in your question.

let acceleration be constant

By definition

$$\frac {dv}{dt}=a$$

Seperating the variables and  integrating the above equation we get

$$\int_{v_1} ^v dv=a\int_0 ^t dt$$

where $v_1 $ is the initial velocity

$$\implies v=v_1+at$$

So it will be wrong if you will apply the formula in the question.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. I understand now

Comment: I am happy that it helped. By the way Enjoy learning.